# Rails "any?" instance method callback?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, callback, any

How to receive the post's ID, if post is found via this *'.any'* call?

```
<% if @posts.any? {|p| p.title == my_title} %>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should probably do it like this:

```
<% if (post = @posts.detect {|p| p.title == my_title} ) %>
  Post ID: <%= post.id %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1):

Any won't return anything except `true` or `false`.

http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Enumerable.html#M001500

if you want to something to be returned, use `select`

http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Enumerable.html#M001488

Answer (score 0):

Do something like the following, get the value if the condition is true. However the following way only set the post_id to the last matched post, if you want all of them, then set post_id as array:

```
<% post_id = nil%>
<% if @posts.any? {|p| post_id = p.id if p.title == my_title; p.title == my_title} %>
```